# WSO2 APIM Analytics 3.2.0 dashboard login page doesn't open

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am running WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 and Analytics 3.2.0 on different client servers. I did all the required settings to configure WSO2 APIM with WSO2 Analytics. Started both the servers successfully and WSO2 APIM URL's open well. But, when I open the Analytics Dashboard URL (https://<Analytics_Host>:9643/analytics-dashboard/login), I get the below warning in the dashboard server logs, and the login page does not appear. Only a blank screen appears.

> WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Unmapped
> exception feign.RetryableException: No subject alternative names
> matching IP address <APIM_IP> found executing GET
> https://<APIM_Host>:9443/api/am/admin/v0.16/custom-urls/carbon.super

In the browser console I can see errors as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

One more thing I noticed is in the management console of WSO2 APIM, difference in Service Providers list when compared with my local. I didn't find all the service providers on the client server which I can see on my local.

WSO2 APIM Carbon Console Service Providers list on my local:

[image]

WSO2 APIM Carbon Console list on the client server:

[image]

Am I missing out on some configurations? Need suggestions on this issue.

Comment: Were you able to export the TLS certs from API Manager and place it under Analytics' `client-truststore.jks`? Further, check whether the TLS cert has a SAN entry with the IP address of the API Manager.

Comment: Athithathan's answer is correct. As he has explained,
1. Goto API Manager's wso2carbon.jks
2. Export mail cert in the keystore (usually with alias wso2carbon by default)
3. Go to API Analytic Dashboard's client-trustore.jks
4. Import previously exported cert in to this client-trustore.jks.

Comment: Hi Athiththan, Yasas, I created new keystore in API-M with its IP address as the CN. Exported the public key and imported in the Analytics client-truststore.jks file. Still the issue persists. And I found in WSO2 documentation that we have to export the public key from Analytics keystore and import it in API-M's client-truststore.jks file. So, I even created new keystore in Analytics with its IP address as the CN, exported the public key and imported in API-M's client-truststore,jks but still the same issue.